# Converting vb6 function to vb.net with Form Manipulation

Tags: wpf, vb.net, vb6

I have a function in vb6 that receives a generic form and then performs various manipulations on that page. 
I'm trying to convert from vb6 to vb.net and wpf.
However i'm at a lost as what to do in this situation as page/Window manipulation is very different from vb6.

I would like to not use the find child function as I think it's very inefficient to do it for each control.

Can anyone help?

The function (partial):

```
Public Function SegurancaControlo(ByRef Frm As Form, ByVal Objecto, Optional ByVal Condicao As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo ErroEm_SegurancaControlo
Dim rss As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SQL As String


' configura controlo
SQL = (..)

If query(SQL, rss, "SYS") Then
    Do Until rss.EOF
    Select Case rss!Property
        Case "E"
            Frm.Controls(rss!NomeObjecto).Enabled = rss!Value
        Case "L"
            If (TypeOf Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName) Is DataGrid) Then
                Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName).AllowUpdate = False
                Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName).AllowAddNew = False
                Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName).AllowDelete = False
            Else
                Frm.Controls(rss!NomeObjecto).Locked = rss!Value
            End If

        Case "V"
            Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName).Visible = rss!Value
        Case "C"
            Frm.Controls(rss!ObjectName).Caption = rss!Value

    End Select
    rss.MoveNext
Loop
End If
(..)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is.  With the exception of the On Error Goto (see Try/Catch block in help) and As ADODB.Recordset (see SQL DataReader or SQL DataSet), your code will run without error in vb.net.

Frm.Controls(ControlName As String).Property

is valid in vb.net.  This code works assuming a textbox named TextBox1 is on the form...

```
  Dim Frm As Form = Me

  Frm.Controls("TextBox1").Enabled = False
  Dim t As String = Frm.Controls("TextBox1").Text
```

Comment: but I'm using wpf not windows forms.  there are no forms just pages and windows